# SQL запрос на связывание таблиц по нескольким полям

Tags: sql, oracle

Требуется связать 2 таблицы. Проблема в том что в одной из таблиц поля для связывания выглядит вот в таком вот формате:

```
635 - Механ-е поврежд-я по АКП - 2 - 1 - 1
```

А во второй таблице эти данные располагаются в 5 разных полях. Попробовал сделать вот такой вот запрос, но он не работает.

```
select * from CONVERSION_ACTS
left join sel_rjs2 on CONVERSION_ACTS.DEFECT_TYPE = (sel_rjs2.id + ' - ' + sel_rjs2.SELECT_DESCRIPTION + ' - ' + sel_rjs2.adr + ' - ' + sel_rjs2.avtor + ' - ' + sel_rjs2.rem)
```

Скрин ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Строки в Oracle конкатенируются оператором `||`, а не `+`

Comment: @Mike точно совсем забыл. Ошибка новичка) Спасибо майк выручаете)

Comment: @Mike а такой ещё вопрос. Допустим мне нужно связать чисто по айдишнику таблицы. И я хочу из `CONVERSION_ACTS.DEFECT_TYPE` выдрать айди. Для моего примера это будет 635. То есть выдрать всё до первого встретившегося пробела. Я могу сделать это на уровне sql? просто не хочется отдельно писать ещё 1 запрос в котором я считаю это поле и буду выдирать уже на уровне c#. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: `regexp_substr(DEFECT_TYPE,'^\d+')`

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое. Очень помогаете. Обязательно почитаю и разберусь как работает что бы понимать всё это.

Comment: @Mike я так понимаю тут не обязательно в sql ударятся ведь regexp просто функция. Тут наверно стоит почитать про регулярки? Что бы запись понимать. Они ведь во всех языках одинаковые? Или есть разница?

Comment: В общих чертах да, я бы предложил отдельно почитать про существующие функции Oracle, что бы иметь представление какие вообще возможности есть. И да, регулярки стоит изучать отдельно. Они во всех языках одни, НО у них куча диалектов и в Oracle используется самый примитивный из них POSIX, в котором есть только базовые конструкции, остальные диалекты скорее его расширения. `^` от  начала строки, `\d` цифра, `+` одна и более

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо.